# Commutator Subgroup of $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I've seen a few similar questions online and including on this website but I do not get the explanation.  A lot of the solutions are general for the dihedral group not for $D_8$ saying stuff along the lines that $y^2$ is the generator and so on. Obviously $D_8$ has two elements $a$ and $b$ one being the rotation the other being the reflection.  $a^4=b^2=e$ and $ba=a^3b$.  The commutator subgroup is $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ so when we say find the commutator subgroup are we just trying to find elements that can be written in that form, but can't only e do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two elements do not commute, their commutator is not the identity. For instance, we have
$$aba^{-1}b^{-1} = aba^3b = abba = a^2$$
You can calculate the commutator of any other two elements as well, but they will all give you either $a^2$ or $e$. So the commutator subgroup of $D_8$ (which, for the record, I prefer to write as $D_4$) is $\{e, a^2\}\cong C_2$.

Note that in some groups, the set of commutators is not actually a subgroup, because the product of two commutators is not necessarily itself a commutator. So the commutator subgroup is the subgroup *generated* by the set of commutators. That's not relevant in this case, thoguh.